# In Java, How can I copy object value to the new Object and change data without impact to another reference variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, dto

I need to print the request body in console with masking data. So I want separate between request object with masking for print to console and the request object for use in business without masking.

So I clone the request object (UnderwriteRequest  request) to new Object (UnderwriteRequest requestMasking) and then I do method to mask data.

But when I set masking ID card to new Object , the reference object (UnderwriteRequest  request) have masking too.

I don't want to mask the (UnderwriteRequest  request) because this object have to use in business logic.

Why have impact to the reference object?
How can I mask data without impact to the reference object?

Thank you.

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<UnderwriteResponse> execute(@RequestBody UnderwriteRequest request) {

        UnderwriteRequest requestMasking = maskingData(request);
}






public static UnderwriteRequest maskingData(UnderwriteRequest request) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    UnderwriteRequest requestMasking = (UnderwriteRequest) request.clone();

    try {
            
            if(request != null) {

                if(request.getRequestBody().getPersonalData().getIdCard() != null && !request.getRequestBody().getPersonalData().getIdCard().isEmpty()) {
            
                        maskIdCard(requestMasking, request);
                
        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
             log.info(e);
    }

    return requestMasking;
}





public static void maskIdCard(UnderwriteRequest requestMasking, UnderwriteRequest request) {
            String maskChar = "X";
            String maskString = StringUtils.repeat( maskChar, 9);
            String idcard = request.getRequestBody().getPersonalData().getIdCard();
                    requestMasking.getRequestBody().getPersonalData().setIdCard(StringUtils.overlay(idcard, maskString, 0, 9));

}



@Getter
@Setter
public class UnderwriteRequest implements Cloneable{


    private RequestHeader requestHeader;
    private RequestBrmsBody requestBrmsBody;
    private RequestBody requestBody;

    private RESPONSE_STATUS status = RESPONSE_STATUS.FAILED;
    private String message;
    
    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }
    
    

    
}
```

I use clone() method to copy object value to new Object.
because I think when I change data in new Object that will not impact to reference object.[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: just google `deep copy`

Comment: clone() is a shallow copy. you ll need to deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the SpringBoot framework. You can take a look at the BeanUtils.copyProperties(); method. This method assigns the same properties to the first object and the second object through reflection. It will not have The problem you mentioned

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is straight forward, you are performing a **shallow copy** because of which the objects references which are there in the original object are shared with the clone object.

In your case it is the PersonalData object which is in the main object.

If you go through the article which you have attached there([java clone](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/)) is another copy which is a **deep copy** and a better explanation is also provided there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).